# What is the master here if I don't provide one?

Tags: apache-spark

According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit should submit my Spark application JAR with

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Even if I start my `SparkSession` with

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .getOrCreate()
```

(thus without a line `.master("local")` or something similar) and have no `--master` option, my application runs. The page http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties says that master has no default. What is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure that runs , because it was giving me the error of master not defined ! Can you please share the SparkConf that you are using inside your Code !

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava: I am not using any SparkConf to my knowledge. How would I find it?

Comment: Can you please paste the code of your main class !

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava: There is nothing happening anymore. However - not sure what the constellation was before - now it fails as expected. Can I add `.master("local")` in  the source code hardcoded and override it with the `--master` option when spark-submit-ting?

Answer (score 1):

- if `spark.master` is set it in the `spark-defaults.conf` it is its value.
- otherwise `local[*]`.

Comment: In what config?

Comment: spark-defaults.conf

Comment: I don't have that file.

Comment: So it is `local[*]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **--master local[n]**

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master local[n] \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but my question was not how to use --master option, but what the default cluster is if I don't use it.