# Do we need to start spark to run pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This may be a novice question. Here is my scenario.

I have installed a spark on my machine. I did not start it yet (using sbin/start-all.sh or any other script from sbin folder).
Then I opened pyspark (using bin/pyspark), it started without any error. 
I tried running sample program:

```
>>> var=sc.textFile('/home/rushikesh/sam.txt')
>>> var.count()
```

It worked without any error.

Question 1: Don't we need spark running for executing pyspark/spark-shell program?

Question 2: Or only Spark-submit needs a spark to start?

Please clarify in case I am missing something.

Comment: You started `pyspark` essentially which is the python wrapper around `spark`, if you start `bin/spark-shell` it will open up a `spark/scala console`

Comment: Very good question. PySpark has a self contained SPRK, which doesn't need any Master-Worker nodes to run.

Answer (score 3):

Pyspark is a Python API for Spark that lets you bind the simplicity of Python and the power of Apache Spark in order to tame Big Data. To use PySpark you will have to install python and Apache spark on your machine. While working with pyspark, running pyspark is enough.

To run pyspark locally on your machine:

pyspark2 --master local[*]

Refer this link in order to install pyspark on windows.
https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c

Answer (score -1):

[By default Spark runs in `local[*]` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658951), which provides non-distributed testing and development environment embedded in a single JVM.

This applies to `spark-shell`, `pyspark`, `spark-submit` and other options alike.

`sbin` scripts are used to start Spark's own [standalone cluster manager](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), normally in a distributed environment. If you use these, you'll also have to properly configure Spark master URL.

That however is only one, of many supported (and 3rd party) cluster managers, that can be used with Spark.

Comment: So you are saying, For non-local mode of spark I need to start spark from sbin scripts, Is It?

Comment: @RushikeshGaradade no you don't need to start spark before hand in either deployment mode. The application should/will create a spark session for you, alternativly the spark-submit command will create a spark session for you and then your application will inherit that spark session.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pure speculation from my side, but I'm putting it here for community's inputs :
PySpark or Spark dependencies (jars) for JVM languages are just APIs to work with Spark. When these APIs are fired, your application searches for existing spark instance which is up and running, if none found, SPARK_HOME env variable is looked at and a new spark instance is launched implicitly.

I am new to Spark (and whole BigData world). I commented here with the hope to restart the discussions on this open thread, as I am also curious about how things work in the scenario OP mentioned. IMO, non-local v/s local doesn't have to do with OP's question. In cluster, I believe, master/worker can be configured separately which on local machine is represented by threads of your spark process. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: FYI Stack Overflow doesn't support "discussions" and questions+answers aren't really "threads." I would suggest posting a new question if you have one, but there's no need to post general opinion/discussion starters (as that's not the purpose of this site), and there's really no reason to cause a 3-year-old question to resurface in the queue (since there's nothing to answer at this point)

Comment: The answer needs to be true or false - or at least give some information around the topic, discussions should be as part of questions and not answers.